# How to flatten a "complex" dictionary into a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following dictionary structure:

```
{'AA': [('No Av', 'Ave', 3.35, 'Max', 0.9, 'Min', -6.8), ('analist disp:', -5.0), u' AA: Jan 11, 2016\t\t\t']}
```

where

```
u' AA: Jan 11, 2016\t\t\t'
```

is just a unicode string.

I would like to flatten it into a list like this:

```
['AA', 'No Av', 'Ave', 3.35, 'Max', 0.9, 'Min', -6.8, 'analist disp:', -5.0, u' AA: Jan 11, 2016\t\t\t']
```

I have tried so many alternatives and nothing works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a recursion function that recurse the dictionary values:

```
d = {'AA': [('No Av', 'Ave', 3.35, 'Max', 0.9, 'Min', -6.8),
            ('analist disp:', -5.0), u' AA: Jan 11, 2016\t\t\t']}


def flat(xs):
    for x in xs:
        if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
            for y in flat(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x

# If there's only one item in the dictionary
next([key] + list(flat(value)) for key, value in d.items())
# => ['AA', 'No Av', 'Ave', 3.35, 'Max', 0.9, 'Min', -6.8, 'analist disp:',
#     -5.0, u' AA: Jan 11, 2016\t\t\t']
```

If there are multiple items, use following instead:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    [key] + list(flat(value)) for key, value in d.items()
))
# => ['AA', 'No Av', 'Ave', 3.35, 'Max', 0.9, 'Min', -6.8, 'analist disp:',
#     -5.0, u' AA: Jan 11, 2016\t\t\t']
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternatives and for the expanation!